# How to iterate over one of the columns of a table and write it to csv file

Tags: matlab, csv, matlab-table

I have a table gTruth.LabelData and have a column called X. I want to iterate over the elements of the column X of the table, and write it into a csv file. How to do it?

The variables in each cell of the X column is of type `double` like `[3 15 26 38;62 9 19 4]`.

Comment: data.(k) is bad command. You can not use this command. You must specify the variable in filed of data, then index the final value.

Comment: yes i have deleted it. data could refer to readtable(filename) but that is also throwing me error. So any advice (from scratch?)

Comment: I can not understand your question clearly.

Comment: Lets forget about `data` thing. Starting from scratch, how can i iterate over the column X of the table and write it to a csv file.

Comment: L = size(X,2)   % number of column

Comment: Can you please clarify what the table looks like? Have you tried using `writetable` ?

Comment: yes i tried that but i get output in wrong format. `data = load('input_filename.mat');
writetable(data.gTruth.LabelData,'output_filename.csv');` this saves all the columns in one csv but it does one strange thing. Suppose i have `580 103 199 41;753 83 1108 83`, i want the first four points to be saved as one row but what it did was `580 753 103 83 199 1108 41 83` - i.e. it is considering column wise. X is one of the columns in the table `data.gTruth.LabelData`. Other columns have only one row but X has upto 4 rows (Above sample of X has 2 rows)

Answer (score 1):

```
L = size(X,2)   % number of column 

for i=1:L  
     valX = X(:,i) 
     xlswrite('MyFile.xlsx',valX)
end
```